# Optimize Postgresql query with order by, left join and limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Im' looking for help as I can't find a good way to optimize this query :

```
SELECT
b.book_id,
b.asin,
b.type_book
FROM book b
LEFT JOIN product_maj_plateforme pmp
        ON pmp.book_id_fk = b.book_id AND pmp.plateforme_id_fk = 1
WHERE
deleted = 0
AND (
        pmp.book_id_fk IS NULL OR (
        pmp.book_id_fk IS NOT NULL
        AND pmp.date_updated < now() - INTERVAL '1 SECOND' * b.ttl
))
AND asin IS NOT NULL
AND asin != ''
AND asin != '0'
AND price_achat > 0
ORDER BY b.ttl asc
LIMIT 400;
```

Right now, here is my execution plan :

```
'Limit  (cost=0.00..8702.51 rows=400 width=20) (actual time=3284.647..3287.175 rows=400 loops=1)'
'  Output: b.book_id, b.asin, b.type_book, b.ttl'
'  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..4499522.06 rows=206815 width=20) (actual time=3284.647..3287.128 rows=400 loops=1)'
'        Output: b.book_id, b.asin, b.type_book, b.ttl'
'        Filter: ((pmp.book_id_fk IS NULL) OR ((pmp.book_id_fk IS NOT NULL) AND (pmp.date_updated < (now() - ('00:00:01'::interval * (b.ttl)::double precision)))))'
'        Rows Removed by Filter: 631559'
'        ->  Index Scan using book_ix_test on public.book l  (cost=0.00..324455.62 rows=620444 width=20) (actual time=0.014..893.522 rows=631959 loops=1)'
'              Output: b.book_id, b.code, b.date_created, b.date_updated, b.titre, b.deleted, b.encours, b.date_encours, b.prix_achat, b.prix_vente, b.marchand_id_achat, b.etat_id_achat, b.poids, b.prix_vente_max, b.prix_vente_conc, b.asin, b.item_condition, b.type_book, b.author, b.edition, b.quantity, b.ttl'
'              Filter: ((b.asin IS NOT NULL) AND ((b.asin)::text <> ''::text) AND ((b.asin)::text <> '0'::text) AND (b.prix_achat > 0::double precision) AND (b.deleted = 0) AND (b.encours = 0))'
'              Rows Removed by Filter: 441235'
'        ->  Index Scan using produit_maj_plateforme_uniq on public.produit_maj_plateforme pmp  (cost=0.00..6.71 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=631959)'
'              Output: pmp.book_id_fk, pmp.date_updated'
'              Index Cond: ((pmp.book_id_fk = b.book_id) AND (pmp.plateforme_id_fk = 1))'
'Total runtime: 3287.333 ms'
```

I think the problem is the Nested Loop Left Join, but I can't find a way to avoid it.

This query take about 10sec to execute on my dedicated 32Gb + ssd server

Thanks in advance

EDIT :

Postgresql version : 9.3 (On Debian)

Table book : ~1200000 lines

```
CREATE TABLE book
(
  book_id serial NOT NULL,
  code character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  date_created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  date_updated timestamp without time zone,
  titre character varying(1000),
  deleted smallint DEFAULT 0,
  encours smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  date_encours timestamp without time zone,
  price_achat double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  price_vente double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  marchand_id_achat integer,
  etat_id_achat integer,
  poids double precision,
  price_vente_max double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  price_vente_conc double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  asin character varying(255),
  item_condition smallint,
  type_livre smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  author character varying(250),
  edition character varying(250),
  quantity smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  ttl integer DEFAULT 64800,
  CONSTRAINT livre_pkey PRIMARY KEY (livre_id)
);

CREATE INDEX book_ix_get_to_be_checked_2
  ON book
  USING btree
  (type_livre DESC, ttl);

CREATE INDEX book_ix_test
  ON book
  USING btree
  (ttl);
```

Table : ~1200000 lines x 6

```
CREATE TABLE product_maj_plateforme
(
  product_maj_plateforme_id serial NOT NULL,
  book_id_fk integer NOT NULL,
  plateforme_id_fk integer NOT NULL,
  date_updated timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT produit_maj_plateforme_pkey PRIMARY KEY (produit_maj_plateforme_id),
  CONSTRAINT book_id_fk_key FOREIGN KEY (book_id_fk)
      REFERENCES book (book_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT plateforme_id_fk_key FOREIGN KEY (plateforme_id_fk)
      REFERENCES plateforme (plateforme_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE RESTRICT
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX produit_maj_plateforme_uniq
  ON produit_maj_plateforme
  USING btree
  (livre_id_fk, plateforme_id_fk);
```

don't worry about misspelled column, I tried to traduct from french to english for better understanding, but it might miss some changes

Comment: Can you give the postgres version, table definitions + indexes and estimate count of records in the tables?

Comment: Also read [`this guideline`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) on postgres performance questions.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: Amazon France product advertising API?

Comment: Yes it's related, I'm building a repricing tool

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the query? What does it do? Maybe there are better ways to get the same information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT
b.book_id,
b.asin,
b.type_book
FROM book b
WHERE deleted = 0          
AND asin != ''
AND asin != '0'
AND price_achat > 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM product_maj_plateforme pmp
                WHERE pmp.book_id_fk = b.book_id AND pmp.plateforme_id_fk = 1
                  AND pmp.date_updated > now() - INTERVAL '1 SECOND' * b.ttl)

ORDER BY b.ttl asc
LIMIT 400;
```

It slightly changes the logic of the query but may suit you and be faster.

Other way to speed up the query is to create a composite index on `(ttl, deleted, asin)` or `(ttl, deleted, price_achat)`

Comment: Thanks ! It looks like it's a good way to have the best perf (It's sad that it uses sub query, but anyway ...)

Answer (score 0):

assuming that deleted, asin and price_achat are part of your book table.
is this any faster?

```
SELECT
b.book_id,
b.asin,
b.type_book
FROM (select * from book where deleted = 0 and asin IS NOT NULL AND asin != '' AND asin != '0' AND price_achat > 0) b
LEFT JOIN product_maj_plateforme pmp
        ON pmp.book_id_fk = b.book_id AND pmp.plateforme_id_fk = 1
WHERE

        pmp.book_id_fk IS NULL OR 
        (
          pmp.book_id_fk IS NOT NULL
          AND pmp.date_updated < now() - INTERVAL '1 SECOND' * b.ttl
        )
ORDER BY b.ttl asc
LIMIT 400;
```

Comment: It wont be faster - postgres query planner pushes predicates to table filters.

Comment: I just tried, but same execution plan and same execution time (thanks anyway)